# WordPress pre_get_posts ordered randomly is duplicating the posts

Tags: php, wordpress

Im using pre_get_posts in wordpress to display my custom post type posts in a random order. Its kinda of working however it always duplicates some of the posts meaning I end up with two of the same post when I click load more. On refresh the posts that are duplicated changes. Is their a way to make it so that it doesn't duplicate the posts?

Below is what I'm using in functions to make it randomly display.

```
    function artist_random_display( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_post_type_archive( 'artist' ) ) {
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'rand' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'artist_random_display' );
```

Answer (score -1):

There is nothing wrong with this function , you just need to add a condition on the page where you are displaying this custom post.